# Undefined subroutine &main::key_enc

Tags: perl

I have a Perl module named McuEnc.pm which is located at /home/eric/temp directory:

```
package McuEnc;

use 5.010;
use strict;
use warnings;
use Exporter qw(import); 

our @EXPORT_OK = qw(key_enc data_enc data_dec); 

sub key_enc { some code }
sub data_enc { some code } 
sub data_dec { some code }

1;
```

I have a Perl script named test.pl which is also located at /home/eric/temp directory:

```
use 5.010;
use strict;
use warnings;
use McuEnc qw(key_enc data_enc data_dec);

key_enc("1111");
...
```

I have changed working directory to /home/eric/temp. Now if I run test.pl script, it runs correctly. But if I create a new directory /home/eric/temp/My and move the McuEnc.pm file into it and then modify the test.pl script as follwoing:

```
use 5.010;
use strict;
use warnings;
use My::McuEnc qw(key_enc data_enc data_dec);

key_enc("1111");
...
```

then I'm getting the following error when I run test.pl again:

```
Undefined subroutine &main::key_enc called at ./test line 6.
```

However, I can still call the subroutine correctly with:

```
McuEnc::key_enc("1111");
```

So why I'm getting the error message? what is wrong?

Comment: Going to make a quick guess and say it's because the `use` statement doesn't match the `package` statement. Try `package My::McuEnc` instead, and see if that dose it?

Comment: It works! Thank you very much.

Comment: @Sobrique you should put that as the answer

Answer (score 0):

This was answered by Sobrique in the comments, but it was never posted as an official answer:

"The `use` statement doesn't match the package statement. Try package `My::McuEnc` instead"